# How to move searchbar in Plone5

Tags: python, plone, plone-4.x, plone-5.x, plone-3.x

I'm new to Plone 5 and I'm actually following the plone training. However, I'm not used to the way that all is build. I would like to do simple things but I don't know where to start. For example:

- How can I move the search bar from the header to the navbar menu?
- How can I add an image to the header next to the logo?
- Is there any tutorial that can help me?

Comment: It's always best to ask Plone questions directly in our forum https://community.plone.org

Comment: This quest resembles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163468/how-to-make-footer-to-show-items-from-main-menu-automatically-in-plone/37180542#37180542

Answer (score 1):

Most of your questions can probably be answered with techniques from the official tutorials and documentation. See:

- https://docs.plone.org/index.html
- https://docs.plone.org/adapt-and-extend/index.html
- https://docs.plone.org/develop/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can install the add-on Products.ContentWellPortlets and replace the top-viewlets with portlets, by adding a `portlets.xml` in one of your add-on's profiles.

This example adds a logo and an image next to it:

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<portlets>

 <!-- Assign Logo-portlet to site-root (key='/'): -->
 <assignment name="top" category="context" key="/"
    manager="ContentWellPortlets.InHeaderPortletManager1"
    type="plone.portlet.static.Static" visible="True">

  <!--
   Give this portlet a name, so we can recognize it easily in the
   portlet-management-UI via `[PLONESITE_URL]/manage-portletsinheader`:
   -->
  <property name="header">Logo</property>

  <!-- But don't show its header and footer when viewing the portlet: -->
  <property name="omit_border">True</property>

  <!-- Replace 'Plone' with your site-id here, in case it differs: -->
  <property name="text">
     &lt;a href="/Plone">
       &lt;img src="logo.png" />
     &lt;/a>
   </property>

 </assignment>

 <!-- Assign another portlet in next column (InHeaderPortletManager2): -->
 <assignment name="top" category="context" key="/"
    manager="ContentWellPortlets.InHeaderPortletManager2"
    type="plone.portlet.static.Static" visible="True">
  <property name="header">Some image next to Logo</property>
  <property name="omit_border">True</property>

  <property name="text">
    &lt;img src="defaultUser.png"
        title="Dummy-user-avatar" />
   </property>

 </assignment>

</portlets>
```

And polish it with some styling.

For the search-box I'd may assign a search-portlet above the content (using ContentWellPortlets), give it a minus-margin-top and for the globnav a margin-right, but as there's many ways to Rome, I'd might replace the globnav with a navigation-portlet, too.

Here's an add-on for illustration-purposes (see its `viewlets.xml` on how to hide the top-viewlets):
https://github.com/ida/adi/tree/master/adi.samplestructure